# How to calculate Gaussian-weighted Circular Window?

Tags: c++, matrix, statistics, gaussian

I have a Matrix with values filled in every Field. The size is e.g. 15x15(225) now I want to calculate the Weight of every Field based on the Center Field of the Matrix. For a bigger distance, the value of the Pixel will be less weighted for the calculation. This should be look like a circle around the center Field. Here a example Image:

[image: Example]

The small Rectangle is the centre field. The weighting should be a Gaussain-weighted circular window with a sigma of 1.5. How could I get this done? My thought was sth. like this where every Weight is filled in a Matrix with the same Size for the calculation afterwards.

```
expf = 1.f/(2.f * 1.5 * 1.5);
[...]
W[k] = (i*i + j*j) * expf;
```

Where i and j are the distanze from the centre pixel (e.g. for first iteration `i = -7, j = -7`)

For me this solution seemed to be fine, but the values I get are always very small e.g:

```
W[0]: 3.48362e-10
W[1]: 6.26123e-09
W[2]: 7.21553e-08
W[3]: 5.3316e-07
W[4]: 2.52596e-06
W[5]: 7.67319e-06
W[6]: 1.49453e-05
[...]
W[40]: 0.000523195
W[41]: 0.000110432
W[42]: 1.49453e-05
W[43]: 1.29687e-06
W[44]: 7.21553e-08
W[45]: 5.3316e-07
W[46]: 9.58266e-06
W[47]: 0.000110432
W[48]: 0.000815988
[...]
W[85]: 0.055638
W[86]: 0.0117436
W[87]: 0.00158933
W[88]: 0.000137913
[...]
W[149]: 7.67319e-06
W[150]: 2.52596e-06
W[151]: 4.53999e-05
W[152]: 0.000523195
W[153]: 0.00386592
```

Could it be, that the calculation of the weights is wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [PDF of a multivariate normal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution) is

*2 π <sup>-k / 2</sup> |Σ|<sup>-0.5</sup>exp(-0.5 ((x - μ) |Σ|<sup>-1</sup> ((x - μ))*

For your case, this translates to

```
double weight(int i, int j, double var) {
    return 1 / (2 * M_PI) * std::exp(-0.5 * (i * i + j * j) / var / var);
}
```

where `i` and `j` are centered at 0 and 0, and `var` is the variance.

Note:

1. This is the PDF. If you want the value to be 1 at the center, use `weight(i, j, var) / weight(0, 0, var)`. Otherwise, you will indeed get small numbers.
2. The decay is specified by `var` - lower values will show larger decay.

---

The following code prints

```
$ g++ --std=c++11 gs.cpp && ./a.out 
1
0.884706
1
4.78512e-06
```

for example

```
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>

double weight(int i, int j, double var) {
    return 1 / (2 * M_PI) * std::exp(-0.5 * (i * i + j * j) / var / var);
}

int main() {
    {
        const double f = weight(0, 0, 20);
        std::cout << weight(0, 0, 20) / f << std::endl;
        std::cout << weight(-7, -7, 20) / f << std::endl;
    }
    {
        const double f = weight(0, 0, 2);
        std::cout << weight(0, 0, 2) / f << std::endl;
        std::cout << weight(-7, -7, 2) / f << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: I' still working myself through the Wiki-Entry to clearly understand everything. But the Example really looks fine. thank you for that!

Comment: @Vincentthe0ne I unfortunately made a mistake in the formula above. Please see current version.

Comment: Ahh well I didn't noticed that but thank you for the correction @AmiTavory. One Question I still have left. How would you set the `var` value, or what would be a reason to make it high or low? Or can I see the `var` just like my sigma?

Comment: @Vincentthe0ne var is indeed like your sigma. I think that only you, knowing the specifics of your problem, can set the rate of decay that fits it.